# how to combine Adjacent keywords into a multi-word keyword depending on their position in the text java

Tags: java, keyword, textrank

I have a list f keywords i used TextRank algorithme, and i have list of all words tokinized ,i want to combine kaywords into a multi-word keyword depending on their position in the list of all words tokenized with java.
For exemple :

```
Keywords :[ management ,activities ,such ,accounting ,risk ,project ,performance]
```

list of all words tokenized :

```
[ "A", "cloud", "service", "for", "managing", "business", "activities", "such", "accounting",",", "procurement", "project", "management",",","risk", "management"," performance","."]
```

Result of multi-Keywords :

```
[ "risk management" ,"activities such accounting","project","management performance"]
```

Answer (score -1):

The results that you want ("multi-word keyword") are *phrases*. We have a Python implementation, for multiple textrank algorithms, which handles that by default – at https://github.com/DerwenAI/pytextrank/

Comment: Please avoid posting link-only answers, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer

Comment: Thank you ,but  i'm searching for java implementation , i already implemented the algorithm to extract keywords, but i didn't understand or  find any solution how to combine keywords to phrases.

Comment: This is not a link-only answer. The question about NLP is answered by the need for key phrase extraction. Implementation of that within the _textgraph_ family of algorithms is much longer than would fit well here, although there are multiple open source projects which show this kind of approach.